# mypy: disallow_any_unimported not working as expected

Tags: python, mypy

I'm adding type annotations to an existing project in python 3.7. The project uses sqlalchemy but I'm not using their stubs since they're incomplete. However, I'd like to annotate attributes on my ORM classes and I'd like mypy to enforce annotation on all of those.

Here's a minimal example to illustrate what I mean:

test.py:

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import as_declarative

@as_declarative
class Base:
    pass

class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'foo'

    oid = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

mypy.ini:

```
[mypy]

[mypy-sqlalchemy.*]
ignore_missing_imports = True

[mypy-test]
disallow_any_unimported = True
```

With this, I was expecting mypy to complain about a missing type on the `oid` attribute which I could then fix with `oid: int = Column(...)`. But I don't get any errors at all.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it seems I misunderstood the purpose of `disallow_any_unimported`. This flag basically seems to cover cases where an unknown type is imported and used in an annotation:

```py
from untyped import Foo

# ...
x: Foo = bar
```

In my case `oid` is *inferred* to be `Any` because *mypy* does not know what `Column()` *returns*.

<s>So it seems the flag I need to use instead is `disallow_any_expr` which disallows the use of `Any` inside any expression.</s>

**edit**: `disallow_any_expr` has the side effect of also disallowing the use of `Integer` in my original example (and potentially other things). Even though the docs say `Any` is still allowed in function calls which I would have expected extends to constructors. So this flag is not the answer to my issue. I couldn't find something more fine grained however.